# C++ compiler not found by Abaqus

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fortran, abaqus, intel-parallel-studio

Abaqus unable to locate C++ compiler. I need to setup an interface between Abaqus and Intel Parallel Studio which requires Visual Studio. No matter what installations or settings I use, Abaqus fails to locate a C++ compiler. The crucial component is Intel Fortran Compiler which can be located.

I tried different versions of Visual Studio:

- 2017 community,
- 2017 enterprise,
- 2015 community,
- 2013 community.

Parallel Studio:

- XE 2019

Abaqus:

- 2018 Research license

Operating system:

- Windows 10 LTSC

All that is running in a Virtual Machine (KVM) in an OpenStack Cloud.

Steps for testing in cmd.exe:

- Implementing the Paths to Visual Studio and Parallel Studio
- vcvars64.bat (Visual Studio)
- cl.exe prog.cpp works fine
- ifortvars.bat (Parallel Studio)
- Fortran compiler works fine
- abaqus info=system (Abaqus)

This finds all crucial components but one, output of the significant section:

> Processor:            Intel Xeon Processor (Skylake, IBRS)
>   Number of CPUs:       4
>   Physical Memory:      46080 MB
>   Virtual Memory:       47807 Available / 52737 Total Mbytes
>   OS Version:           Windows 10 Enterprise N LTSC 2019  (Build 17763)
>   C++ Compiler:         Unable to locate or determine the version of a
>   C++ compiler on this system.  If a C++ compiler is installed on this system, please load vcvars64.bat file before running Abaqus 
>   Linker Version:       Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.16.27031.1   > Fortran Compiler:    Intel Fortran Compiler 19.0
>   MPI:                  MS-MPI 5.0.12435.6
>   Browser:              Firefox 66.0.3.0

Answer (score 1):

you have to execute:

```
ifortvars.bat intel64 vs2013
```

the parameters depend on your system and the visual studio version required. If you have default abaqus environment configuration this command does everything you need.

Where the bat file is located depends on version of intel compiler and your installation. In my case it is in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2016\windows\bin\ifortvars.bat
```

you execute this command before launching abaqus command in the command prompt or you have to add a call to it to abaqus.bat file

Comment: Thanks for your hint, UN4.

We included the path to ifortvars.bat in the call to Abaqus CAE call (start menu). When we call Abaqus by double clicking cae files, it doesn't recognize the compilers, when we call it from the Windows Startmenu, it works fine now.

This fixes our problem.

Comment: For best effect you should add it to abaqus.bat in your SIMULIA/Commands folder.